# Showing A is negative definite is same as showing -A is positive definite proof

Tags: linear-algebra

I was wondering how to show: $A$ is negative definite iff $-A$ is positive definite

So I know that $A$ is negative definite if $\bf x^TA\bf x$ < $0$ for all $\bf x \neq$ $0$

If I multiply by $-1$ the equality sign is flipped and I get $\bf x^T$-$A\bf x$ > $0$

Is this pretty much the proof? Also, supposed $A$ has an eigenvalue of $0$, would that imply that $A$ is indefinite; since we know positive definite requires eigenvalues strictly greater than $0$ and negative definite requires eigenvalues strictly less than $0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's pretty much the proof. You are using the fact that if $A$ and $B$ are two matrices of compatible size so that $AB$ is defined, then $-(AB) = (-A)B = A(-B)$. Therefore, $-(x^T A x) = x^T(-(Ax)) = x^T((-A)x) = x^T(-A)x$.

If $0$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, then $A$ cannot be strictly positive definite or strictly negative definite. (Some authors allow $\geq 0$ and $\leq 0$ in the definitions of positive definite and negative definite, but I assume you do not use that convention.) If $v$ is an eigenvector corresponding to the zero eigenvalue, then $Av = 0$, hence $v^T A v = 0$, contradicting $x^T A x > 0$ for all nonzero $x$.